# How to change format for %date% in command prompt?

Tags: date, cmd, command-prompt, dayofweek

How do I can change the output format of `echo %date%` in command prompt? In one system I receive the output as `Wed 02/12/2014` but in another system I receive the output as `02/12/2014`. Command I am typing on both the systems is `echo %date%`.

What I basically need to find out is Day of Week. So if can’t change the format then is there any other command in the command-line to get the Day of week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was posted recently and should work the same on any PC after XP Home.

```
@echo off  
set "daysofweek=Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday"  
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /Format:csv') do set "daynumber=%%a"
for /F "tokens=%daynumber% delims=," %%b in ("%daysofweek%") do set "dow=%%b"
echo "%dow%", "%daynumber%"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks! I am able to get the day of week with this. My plan was to get day as well as date from command %date%. But this should be fine. I can use this query to get day and use %date% to get the current date. Thanks

Comment: You can also use wmic to get a reliable date and time in any locale or PC after XP Home.  I've posted the code many times. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fullstamp